# Identify circuits/loops in GPS track data

Tags: postgis, gps, geometric-network, tracking, movement-data

I have a GPS time series with a set of lat/long coordinates per second, how would you go about identifying circuits/loops in that GPS track?

To the layman, it seems like something that should be possible, but I suspect it could just as well be a tremendously complicated problem.

Answer (score 1):

The way to do this is to turn your tracklog into a line, [this](https://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/plugins_gps.html) might help. Then you can detect self-intersections in the line using [topology](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html). The logic for this is for there to be a loop the line must cross itself at some point.

Links are for [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/), which I assume you are using to view your PostGIS data; if you're not it doesn't cost much (it's free) and does a lot of things, it would be worth the download.

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer solved your problem can you please click on the tick next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform map-matching of your GPS data on the road/bike topological network. 
Then you can check if the resulting path contains circles using standard graph analysis method.

Comment: Why is the map-matching step necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by first intersecting the linestrings with themselves, then applying `st_linemerge`.  Any records with multilinestring geometries contain self intersections.  You can then find the self intersection points by finding the duplicate vertices:

```
with ps as (
  select id, (st_dumppoints(geom)).* 
  from (
    select st_linemerge(st_intersection(a.geom,b.geom)) geom, a.id 
    from your_table a, your_table b 
    where a.id = b.id
    ) foo where st_numgeometries(geom) > 1
)
select distinct a.id, a.geom 
from ps a 
join ps b 
on st_equals(a.geom,b.geom) and a.id = b.id and a.path[1] != b.path[1];
```

[image]